# Change html svg cricle's fill with css when clicked on

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using the following svg drawing as a button:

```
<svg id="button-more-people" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;">
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" fill="#F44336" id="circle-button-more-people"/>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" x="11" y="44" font-family="Verdana">+</text>
</svg>
```

When the mouse hovers over the circle, I scale the button up through css:

```
#button {
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);   
}
```

What I can't seem to achieve is to change the buttons color when its clicked on. I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
#button:active ~ circle {
    fill: #D50000;
}
```

I would prefer if there was a javascript-less solution to this I could use.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the selector used for the `fill`:

```
#button:active ~ circle {
```

This is the [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) which in your case matches `<circle>` tags that are siblings and after the `#button`, however in your markup `<circle>` is a child of `#button`

You can solve this by either using a descendant combinator:

```
#button:active circle {
```

Or a child combinator:

```
#button:active > circle {
```

Example:

```css
#button-more-people {
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#button-more-people:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#button-more-people:active circle {
  fill: #D50000;
}
```

```html
<svg id="button-more-people" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;">
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" fill="#F44336" id="circle-button-more-people"/>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" x="11" y="44" font-family="Verdana">+</text>
</svg>
```